# How to select the following nearest element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is the structure:

[image]

I want toggle `ul.children` by clicking `a.exchand-cat-item`. I tried this:

```
$('a.expand-cat-item').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings('ul.children').toggle('slow');
});
```

But then realized that it doesn't work because `ul.children` is one level up in the DOM tree of `a.exchand-cat-item`

What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to first climb back up to the `div` element:

```
$(this).closest('div').siblings('ul.children');
```

Comment: Or, a bit more roundabout but less likely to go wrong if the html structure is modified, `$(this).closest('li.cat-item').find('ul.children')`

Comment: @dbaseman Thanks that worked. I think the problem is that I thought that `closest` only applied to elements "up" in the DOM tree.

Comment: @alexchenco - `closest()` _does_ apply only to elements _up_ in the tree, as in, it finds the closest ancestor...

Answer (score 1):

Then go up one level and use `siblings`:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('ul.children');
```